# text not displayed on img:hover

Tags: html, css

I want to display a text and blur the image on hover.
The blurring works but the text is never displayed.

**CSS:**

```
#d1{
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1100px;
  left: 285px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
 }

#bg2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 898px;
    }  

#bg2:hover {
    filter: blur(5px) grayscale(1) brightness(.3);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px) grayscale(100%) brightness(.3);
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(0);
   -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}

#bg2:hover #d1{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="F2L.html">
   <img src="f2l.JPG" id="bg2" alt="">
  <p id="d1">F2L</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

bg2 is the image id.

d1 is the text id.

Comment: If you want text to be displayed on hover, why not just fill in the 'alt' field on the 'img' tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a problem with your selector  `#bg2:hover #d1`. it shows that `#d1` is inside `#bg2`,instead `#d1` and `#bg2` are siblings. the code must be:

```
#bg2:hover ~ #d1{
  visibility: visible;
}
```